# Unable to get back the Order Details from Firebase 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make an Amazon Clone. I am at the last stage of Displaying the final order after payment confirmation from Stripe. Everything is working perfectly except that I am unable to get the order details back from firebase. I will be grateful for any help. thank You.

I have added the payment.js and order.js file. Also I have attached the image of the firebase structure. The structure looks like this db-- "Users"-- user?.uid--"orders". And I want to sort the order by date.

```
///This is my Orders.js file

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "./firebase";
import "./Orders.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import Order from "./Order";
import {
  getDoc,
  onSnapshot,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  doc,
  addDoc,
  setDoc,
  updateDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { query, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";

function Orders() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      async function fetchData() {
     
        const q = query(
          collection(db, "Users", user?.uid, "orders"),
          orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
        );
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          setOrders({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        });
      }
    } else {
      setOrders([]);
      console.log(setOrders);
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="orders">
      <h1>Your Orders is Here</h1>
      <div className="orders__order">
        {orders?.map((order) => (
          <Order order={order} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Orders;
```

```
///This is payment.js where I am pushing the order details to the firebase database. I am successful in updating the database



import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Payment.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import axios from "./axios";
// import { db } from "./firebase";
import {
  getFirestore,
  doc,
  addDoc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  setDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, collection, auth, firebaseApp } from "./firebase";

function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const history = useNavigate();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge a customer
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        // Stripe expects the total in a currencies subunits
        url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
      });
      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
    };

    getClientSecret();
  }, [basket]);

  console.log("THE SECRET IS >>>", clientSecret);
  console.log("", user);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(async ({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation

        const colRef = doc(db, "Users", user?.uid, "orders", paymentIntent.id);
        const gameSnap = await getDoc(colRef);
        const game = gameSnap.data();
        setDoc(
          colRef,
          {
            basket: basket,
            amount: paymentIntent.amount,
            created: paymentIntent.created,
          },
          { merge: true }
        );
        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_BASKET",
        });

        history("/orders", { replace: true });
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Listen for changes in the CardElement
    // and display any errors as the customer types their card details
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout (<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>

        {/* Payment section - delivery address */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__address">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
            <p>123 React Lane</p>
            <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Payment section - Review Items */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__items">
            {basket.map((item) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                rating={item.rating}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* Payment section - Payment method */}
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__details">
            {/* Stripe magic will go */}

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />

              <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeparator={true}
                  prefix={"$"}
                />
                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>

              {/* Errors */}
              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

```
// This is my order.js where I am trying to use the data pulled from firebase.


import React from "react";
import "./Order.css";
import moment from "moment";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";

function Order({ order }) {
  return (
    <div className="order">
      <h2>Order </h2>
      <p>{moment.unix(order.data.created).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mma")}</p>
      <p className="order__id">
        <small>{order.id}</small>
      </p>
      {order.data.basket?.map((item) => (
        <CheckoutProduct
          id={item.id}
          title={item.title}
          image={item.image}
          price={item.price}
          rating={item.rating}
          hideButton
        />
      ))}
      <CurrencyFormat
        renderText={(value) => (
          <h3 className="order__total">Order Total: {value}</h3>
        )}
        decimalScale={2}
        value={order.data.amount / 100}
        displayType={"text"}
        thousandSeparator={true}
        prefix={"$"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Order;
```

[image: Firebase Structure]

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share your Firestore structure to try to replicate your issue?

Comment: I have edited the question and attached some more files and firebase structure. Could you please look into the issue?  The structure looks like this db-- "Users"-- user?.uid--"orders". This is the image URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkyVm.png

Comment: Can you please keep the code related to query (and where you think the problem is) only?

Comment: Have you checked any typo error between Order and Orders (with and without the “s” letter)? Have you missed some imports inside order.js? It’s not clear how you are using Order in Orders.js to get data from Firestore.